# Can't increment index after swap JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Got a algorithm problem that shifts zeroes to the end of an array without making a new array. This naïve solution doesn't work because it doesn't like the idx++. I'm confused because I'm incrementing the idx AFTER the swap. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
function zeroesToEnd(a) {
  const numOfZeores = a.filter((i) => i === 0).length;
  let idx = a.length - numOfZeores;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let curr = a[i];

    if (curr === 0) {
      let temp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[idx];
      a[idx] = temp;
      idx++; //Won't let me do this
    }
  }

  return a;
}

console.log(zeroesToEnd([1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5]));
```

Comment: What do you mean "won't let me do this"? Or the equally confusing "it doesn't like the idx++"?

Comment: Syntax error (line 11): I don't like that

Comment: So (one) problem is that you don't check if idx goes past the end of the array, you eventually end up every time through the loop adding another element with `a[idx] = temp` so the for loop never exits because the length of the array keeps growing. I'm guessing that's what you meant by "doesn't like it" because eventually the process/tab runs out of memory and crashes.

Comment: The main `for( let i = 0...)` loop is too long. It should only loop through the first `a.length-numOfZeroes` entries. Otherwise you create the problem identified by @JaredSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that *"it doesn't like the idx++"* or *"doesn't let me do this"*. That `idx++` is executing fine.

The problem is that you get into an infinite loop, following a cascade of events:

- When a zero is swapped *forward*, this same zero will be visited again in one of the next iterations;
- Also this second time, a swap will be performed, moving that zero forward again;
- So the number of swaps that are executed will be more than there are zeroes, and by consequence `idx` will become greater than expected;
- This means that a next swap will **create** a new entry at `idx` in the array, making the array longer;
- By consequence the loop condition will remain true forever, as `i` never reaches the end of this growing array.

You should avoid that the same zero is moved more than once, and so `i` should never get into the partition of the array where all zeroes must end up. Not related to this problem, but you should make sure that `a[idx]` is **not** zero when you intend to make a swap, otherwise the swap is not moving anything.

Here is your code with those two corrections (marked with a comment):

```js
function zeroesToEnd(a) {
  const numZeroes = a.filter((i) => i === 0).length;
  let idx = a.length - numZeroes;
  // We only want to move zeroes that are misplaced:
  //  Don't allow i to enter the partition where all zeroes must end up
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length - numZeroes; i++) { 
    let curr = a[i];

    if (curr === 0) {
      // Make sure to swap with a non-zero value
      while (a[idx] === 0) idx++; 
      let temp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[idx];
      a[idx] = temp;
      idx++;
    }
  }

  return a;
}

console.log(zeroesToEnd([1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5]));
```